# Retrieving lists from SharePoint using php

Tags: sharepoint-online, list, php

I am using the library https://github.com/thybag/PHP-SharePoint-Lists-API for accessing the whole lists in SharePoint using php.

I am able to get a connection with SharePoint.I am giving the code below used by me

```
<?php

require_once('SharePointAPI.php');
require_once('SoapClientAuth.php');
$useNtlm=TRUE;
$sp = new SharePointAPI('sample@sampletechnologies.onmicrosoft.com', 'Sample@nt1', 'https://sample-public.sharepoint.com/_vti_bin/Lists.asmx?WSDL',TRUE);


$sp->setReturnType('object');

$data = $sp->getLists();
var_dump($data);

?>
```

Here I am not able to get connection also .

> It may be maintained or configured incorrectly.

I will be thankful if I solve the problem using the same above library.

Comment: @carl please look at this issue:
http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/204615/get-list-of-all-documents-from-sharepoint-using-php

Answer (score 2):

Just to say, if you are using SharePoint online, it uses a different authentication method to standard SharePoint. I've now added support for it in the latest version of the library so it may be worth having a try with something like:

```
use Thybag\SharePointAPI;
$sp = new SharePointAPI('<username>', '<password>', '<path_to_WSDL>', 'SPONLINE');
```